# How to programmatically manipulate SCSS?

Tags: python, css, ruby, node.js, sass

I'm trying to find a tool to parse and manipulate SCSS. What I need to do is programmatically "merge" two versions of SCSS files from different sources.

The use cases involve files that only differ in declarations within the rules and not two totally different SCSS files.

For example, if I have the following files:

```
// foo/sample.scss
$myColor: #fff;
body { background-color: $myColor; margin: 0; }

// bar/sample.scss
$myColor: #ccc;
$black: #000;
body { background-color: $myColor; color: $black; }
```

It would be cool to have a tool in which you could do something like:

```
var sass = require('some-sass-parsing-lib'),
  fooFile = sass.parse({source: 'foo/sample.scss', otherOption: 'value'}),
  barFile = sass.parse({source: 'bar/sample.scss', otherOption: 'value'});

function findFooRuleSomehow () {
  // this would be implemented by the developer, not a part of the lib
}

function hasDeclaration (rule, declaration) {
  // return wether `rule` has a declaration `declaration`
}

barFile.stylesheet.rules.forEach(function (barRule) {
  var fooRule = findFooRuleSomehow();

  rule.declarations.forEach(function (barDeclaration) {
    if (!hasDeclaration(fooRule, barDeclaration)) {
      fooRule.declarations.append(declaration);
    }
  });
  // do the same with variables, etc.
});

sass.save(fooFile, 'result/sample.scss');  // produces the updated version of the SASS file (not CSS)
```

and produce something like:

```
// result/sample.scss
$myColor: #fff;
$black: #000;
body { background-color: $myColor; color: $black; margin: 0; }
```

Which, for example, would allow you to merge only new declarations from `bar/sample.scss` into `foo/sample.scss`.

I found [`reworks/css`](https://github.com/reworkcss/css) which actually allows you to do a very similar behavior to what I'm looking for but this one either a) only works for CSS (not SCSS) or b) I couldn't find what options to use so that it works for SCSS too.

There is also [`node-sass`](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) but it only renders the input to CSS, with no programmatic manipulation options.

Do you know any tool for this you can recommend or point me to? A `nodejs`-based tool would be ideal but I'm open to alternatives in `ruby` or `python`.

Comment: Have you tried libsass? (Meaning it's implementation in your favourite programming language) Check this: http://sass-lang.com/libsass

Comment: Yes I have, and as far as I've seen, these implementations only compile SASS into CSS :( they're very good packages but not what I need. I need to be able to programatically modify the source before compilation. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, this was just my first intention. Now after having a closer look to that projects I must say you are right. However, they are a good starting point. You'll need to extract the code which parses the scss files and create something new around this. Its not a 5 minute job, but I think it is possible.. btw, I cannot understand why they put this question *on hold as off-topic*. Placed reopen-vote.

Comment: Tool requests are off topic for SO.

Comment: Even though it is a tool request, the problem to solve with such tool is very specific and, from my point of view, unlikely to be opinionated since it's not an broad topic. One can stick to *facts* to why X tool would be better suited to solve X *problem*.
Having said that, of course I might be missing the real "why" that turned this question off-topic. So, if this is off-topic for SO, where does this question belong and why there? Thanks for any clarification :)